# Why does JQuery only display HTML characters when enclosed in other tags?

Tags: jquery, html, utf-16

I'm curious about why this JQuery renders the full block HTML character:

```
var html = $('<div>&#9608;</div>');
$("body").append(html)
```

But this doesn't:

```
var html = $('&#9608;');
$("body").append(html)
```

Is there a way to render one single special character (by HTML or hex) without enclosing tags?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/G2Km8/2/

Comment: short answer is html method uses regex to parse for tags, strip unwanted tags like script tags,`<html>` tag, title tag etc and determine if string starts as a tag etc. You just seem to have an edge case using `&` at beginning of string wich is not likely very common

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because JQuery treats your second case as a CSS selector rather than an HTML fragment. Since you probably don't have any elements matching "&#6908;" in your document, you are basically appending an empty set of elements to your body.

try using directly

```
$("body").append('&#9608');
```

This prevents JQuery from having to guess if your string is and HTML fragment or a CSS selector. When passed a String, the append method assumes it is an HTML fragment.

Comment: Thanks very much - that makes sense. Think the above needs an extra semi-colon e.g. `$("body").append('&#9608;');`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the $ sign for the var

Check this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/G2Km8/4/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var html = "&#9608;";
    $("body").append(html);
  });
});
```